# Change usb wifi adapter ip on local network

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, vmware, parallels

I have two Kali virtual machines, one running on Parallels Desktop and one running in VMware Fusion. I use the same usb wifi adapter for both. The issue is-- the Kali on vmware gets the same IP addr as the Kali running on Parallels. I'm not running them at the same time. This is a problem when I ssh to my mac os host because of the duplicate IPs my host refuses the connection of the VMware Kali because it already accepted the Keys from Parallels Kali with the same IP. The IP seems to be bound to the MAC address of the usb wifi adapter. How can I get separate IPs from the same usb wifi adapter? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you SSHing _to_ the macOS host or _from_ the macOS host? I can't see how this could be a problem when the host is merely accepting connections from VMs, as SSH servers do not "accept keys" in any way that requires unique client IPs – only SSH clients do that.

Comment: Also: What DHCP client does Kali use? Can you find out?\

Comment: SSHing to mac os from Kali--

Comment: Kali uses isc-dhcp-server

Comment: That's a DHCP server – not the same thing as a DHCP *client.* Is Kali using isc-dhcp-client (dhclient) as well, or something else? But if you're SSHing to macOS, I really don't see how macOS would care about two clients having the same IP address – no other SSH server does. What kind of error message are you getting from it?

Answer (score 0):

The message I was getting was ‘the man in the middle attack’ and my Mac refused to connect. As I said I believe it was because I had two different virtual machines using the same IP with the same Wi-Fi adapter —something in my Mac OS host system flagged it suspicious. I rebooted my router and now even though each virtual machine has the identical IPs the macOS is allowing me to connect. Thanks for your input.